# Qual o intervalo definido por range no Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Quando eu defino

```
for i in range (5):
```

Meu range vai percorre 0,1,2,3,4,5 ou 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Por curiosidade, por quê não testou antes de perguntar?

Comment: Depende do resto do código e do ambiente. Pode até tocar uma música, dependendo das modificações e versão do interpretador. Pode dar mais detalhes do que aconteceu de errado quando tentou?

Answer (score 1):

Irá gerar 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4
Normalmente, o primeiro parametro de range é o número inicial, o segundo é o final porém excludente. No seu exemplo, range(5), o python assume que o parâmetro inicial é igual a 0. Ele irá gerar os números baseado nesta condicao: maior/igual a zero e menor que 5.

Answer (score -1):

No Python a contagem começa do zero, então:

```
list(range(5))
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: `list(range(5))` retorna `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: opa, foi erro meu aqui na pressa de digitar. vou editar.